# visual basic declare a object and use on all the form

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB and I got a question hope some expert will teach me.**Thanks**

Is it possible to declare a object and use on everywhere without repeat the same thing.

Example

## Form1

Dim object as Integer
Object1 = "123"

## Form2

Messagebox.show(object1)

Comment: Declare it in a module.

Comment: Hi Guy I got it already thank for your help in my school project.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Module file and declare in it as 
`Global object as Integer Object1 = "123"`
Its been quite a long while since I have coded in vb, please forgive me if this doesn't work or if what I'm saying is wrong.

Comment: `Global` is not a keyword in VB.Net. It should be `Public object1 as Integer = 123`.